# Validation of Viewstate Mac Failed, not using cluster, <machine key> doesn't solve

Tags: asp.net

I've found a few similar questions to this on here, but none of them answers have solved it for me.

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

When I set enableViewStateMac = false in web.config, the problem goes away, but I've read that I should never do this.

Most of the answers on here say to define a machine key in system.web, but that doesn't affect the problem at all for me. Same error message.

I'm not using a Web Farm.

Comment: does it happen only on pages using page touting or url rewriting ?